# Increment Number

Tags: php, jquery

What is the best way to increment a number on the background? I've been searching about jQuery countdown and was not lucky. So basically, you set the initial number, and it keeps on increment even if you close the site. Using jQuery or PHP perhaps.

Comment: First ask your self, why do you want to increment number? and what will you do with the number?

Comment: Why is it incrementing? Whats it counting?

Comment: Removed tags from title

Answer (score 0):

"even if you close the site"?? In that case you need to do something in the server side, some database to storage that counter.

I think the best solution is to save an initial timestamp value and then, when you need it, take the current timestamp and "the counter" is the difference between that 2 timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

> So basically, you set the initial number, and it keeps on incrementing
>   even if you close the site.

To achieve this you will have to store number in database. To set initial number you can have different logic to do this.

> what is the best solution to increment a number on the background?

To increment number in background you will need some script running in background which will increment number in database ex CRON Job.